# 'tuple' has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, arrays, tuples

Im trying to get this code to select a random value from this 'deck of cards', remove the selected 'card' and then append it to used_deck

```
deck = [('ad','ah','ac','as'),('2d','2h','2c','2s'),('3d','3h','3c','3s'),('4d','4h','4c','4s'),('5d','5h','5c','5s'),('6d','6h','6c','6s'),('7d','7h','7c','7s'),('8d','8h','8c','8s'),('9d','9h','9c','9s'),('td','th','tc','ts'),('jd','jh','jc','js'),('qd','qh','qc','qs'),('kd','kh','kc','ks')]
used_deck=[]

a = random.randint(0,len(deck))
try:
    b = random.randint(0,3)
    card = [a][b]
except:
    try:
        b = random.randint(0,2)
    except:
        try:
            b = random.randint(0,1)
        except:
            b = 0

print(deck[a][b],'\n')
user_deck.append(deck[a][b])
print(user_deck)
deck[a].pop(b)
print(deck)
```

However when running this code i get the error:

```
deck[a].pop(b)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

Im assuming that .pop cant be used the way i have used it, but all websites i have looked at are using it in the same way i am?

Comment: You return four values for instance, `'ad','ah','ac','as'` and receive them using a single variable `deck`  This is what is called a `tuple`. How about yopu ocnvert it into a list, remove and then convert it back to the tuple?

Comment: you probably should be using try / except like this - you have code in try blocks that should never throw errors, and other bits of code that will almost always throw errors. You should also except specific errors as a rule, otherwise you end up catching errors you didn't know were there.

Comment: for example randint is inclusive so there is a 1 in 13 chance that your first index is out of list range (allowable values are 0 to 12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, meaning they cannot be changed after they are created. You can learn more about them from here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences.

If you want to modify the data within something, it should be contained in a mutable data structure. In this case, a list would work fine.

Here is an example of how you could do it:

```py
import random


deck = [['ad', 'ah', 'ac', 'as'], ['2d', '2h', '2c', '2s'], ['3d', '3h', '3c', '3s'], ['4d', '4h', '4c', '4s'], ['5d', '5h', '5c', '5s'], ['6d', '6h', '6c', '6s'], ['7d', '7h', '7c', '7s'], ['8d', '8h', '8c', '8s'], ['9d', '9h', '9c', '9s'], ['td', 'th', 'tc', 'ts'], ['jd', 'jh', 'jc', 'js'], ['qd', 'qh', 'qc', 'qs'], ['kd', 'kh', 'kc', 'ks']]

used_deck = []

card_type = random.choice(deck)
card = random.choice(card_type)
card_type.remove(card)
used_deck.append(card)

print('Card: {}'.format(card))
print('Used deck: {}'.format(used_deck))
print('Deck: {}'.format(deck))
```

Comment: If the last value in one of the lists is removed, is there a way to get rid of that list? or will it have to just stay empty?

Comment: @peterwelsh Yes, it is possible to remove the list once it is empty. After removing the card from the card_type list, check if it is empty: "if not card_type:". If it is, then call deck.remove(card_type). I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You are using tuples, those are inmutables, why you dont use lists?

`deck = [['ad','ah','ac','as']`

instead

```
 [('ad','ah','ac','as')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
deck_list = list(deck)   # Convert to list
deck_list.pop(a)

print(deck_list)
deck = tuple(deck_list)  # Convert back to tuple
```

Answer (score 2):

A tuple is what is known as a immutable object.
On *immutable sequences* [from the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html):

> Immutable sequences
>
> An object of an immutable sequence type cannot change once it is created. (If the object contains references to other objects, these other objects may be mutable and may be changed; however, the collection of objects directly referenced by an immutable object cannot change.)

You can either change the tuple to a list:

```
a = (1, 2, 3)
a = list(a)
a.pop(0)
```

, or iterate over the tuple:

```
a = (1,2,3)
a = [ i for (idx, i) in enumerate(a) if idx != 0 ]
```

there are probably other methods as well.

Answer (score 0):

> deck[a].pop(b)
>
> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'pop'

`a` is an integer so `deck[a]` is an item from the list `deck`, which gives a tuple. That is, `deck[a]` is a tuple, which does not have a pop attribute/method.

```
deck.pop(a)
```

would remove an item (a tuple) with index `a` from the list named `deck`.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the index you might also use this:

```
def tuple_pop(t: tuple, idx: int) -> tuple:
    return (*t[:idx], *t[idx+1:])

print(tuple_pop((0,1, 2), 0))  # outputs (1, 2)
print(tuple_pop((0,1, 2), 1))  # outputs (0, 2)
print(tuple_pop((0,1, 2), 2))  # outputs (0, 1)
```

I've also added the types do function definition as it's getting more famous these days.